# Magento Shopping cart price rule with free shipping and discount

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, coupon-codes

I'm trying to set up a `shopping cart price rule` to create a customer `coupon code` that accomplishes two goals:

**IF customer apply coupon code then**

> 1) 20% off all customer

**and**

> 2) free shipping(only if quantity is less than 12)

**If you buy more than 12 item,then free shipping will NOT be available,but 20% off will be there.**

**If total items quantity is less than or equal to 12, then 20% off and free shipping will be there(both).**

Answer (score 0):

Override Free Shipping Model and add condition for qty and if qty not match with required qty then return false

Comment: ok checking & let you know